# socket Exception while making post request on HTTPS server with httpClient

Tags: c#, .net, rest, tcp, httpclient

I am trying to post a byte array to a HTTPS site and I get timeout error. Also Getting very slow response. I am sending multiple packets of byte array, some packed I get status 200 and some packet fails.

here headers is Cnonce calculated for digest authentication

```
HttpContent contentss = new ByteArrayContent(array1);
contentss.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = headers;
// httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
// contentss.Headers.

var response1 = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://192.168.1.1/fwup_install", contentss);
Console.WriteLine(response1.StatusCode);
Console.WriteLine(response1.Content);
```

Comment: exception:

OK
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent
OK
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent
An error occurred while sending the request.
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)